# How to make axios.get synchronous?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, axios, cheerio

This is my nodejs code for a 1337x.to scraper. What I wanted to do was first **scrape** the search results which worked fine and then from those search results, get the url of the torrents and **scrape** the magnet url links which seemed to work as a different function but when I tried to **scrape** those values inside the getTorrent function, it just returned undefined and I can't seem to store those values. Can anyone help me with this? I just need to store the magnet links in the array before it is returned.

This is the code:

```
const axios = require('axios')
const cheerio = require('cheerio')

const baseurl = 'https://1337x.to'


var magneturl = 'sdkllfklajds'

var arr = []
var nameList = []
var urlList = []
var seedList = []
var leechList = []
var dateList = []
var sizeList = []

const getMagnet = (torurl) => {
    axios.get(torurl).then(({data}) => {
        var $ = cheerio.load(data)
        $ = cheerio.load($('.dropdown-menu').html())
        magneturl = $('a').last().attr('href')
    })
    return magneturl
}

const getTorrent = (searchurl) => {
    axios.get(searchurl).then(({ data }) => {
        const $ = cheerio.load(data)

        $('.coll-1.name').each((index, element) => {

            var tag = $(element).children('a').last()
            var name = tag.text()
            var url = tag.attr('href')

            getMagnet(url).then((data) => {
                urlList.push(data)
            })

            if(name.length) {
                nameList.push(name)
                //urlList.push(url)
            }
        })

        $('.coll-2').each((index, element) => {
            var seeds = $(element).text()
            if(index > 0)
                seedList.push(seeds)
        })

        
        $('.coll-3').each((index, element) => {
            var leeches = $(element).text()
            if(index > 0)
                leechList.push(leeches)
        })

        
        $('.coll-date').each((index, element) => {
            var dateAdded = $(element).text()
            if(index > 0)
                dateList.push(dateAdded)
        })

        
        $('.coll-4.size').each((index, element) => {
            var size = $(element).text().replace($(element).children('span').text(), '')
            sizeList.push(size)
        })

        var i = 0

        while(i < 20) {
            arr.push({name: nameList[i], url: baseurl + urlList[i], seeds: seedList[i], leeches: leechList[i], dateAdded: dateList[i], size: sizeList[i]})
            i = i + 1
        }
    
    })
    return arr
}

module.exports = {getTorrent, getMagnet}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doubling then/await. When using `await` you can do this:

```js
const getMagnet = async (torurl) => {
    var data = await axios.get(torurl)

     var $ = cheerio.load(data)
      $ = cheerio.load($('.dropdown-menu').html())
      magneturl = $('a').last().attr('href')
     return magneturl
}
```

Basically use the return of the `await` directly instead of in a `then`. Elsewhere in the code you have the same thing.

I think that if you clear up your code like this, you can untangle your promises inside promises, that might solve your issue.

Comment: My problem lies in this block of code but I will try changing that too. Tried that and it is now returning a promise pending.

async () => {
                await axios.get(url).then(({data}) => {
                    var getdata = cheerio.load(data)
                    getdata = cheerio.load(getdata('.dropdown-menu').html())
                    urlList.push(getdata('a').last().attr('href'))
            })
        }

Comment: You should really read about async/await. The point of using those is to make your code that included promises a bit more readable. You are using async/await even inside promises (`then`), while it's better to use only 1 sort of promise coding. Either use async/await, or use `then`, and remember inside `then` you can also return new promises.

Comment: Let me edit the code and try. I will edit the code above so make sure to check that because I don't think that will solve my problem. The getMagnet code when put inside the getTorrent code, doesn't work as it should.

Comment: I am very very close to giving up on nodejs. I have been stuck on this problem for days and have found no real solution to it. The getMagnet function has to be separate or its code has to be written inside the getTorrent function. I tried them both but all I have gotten are promises upon promises. I got the getTorrent to work somehow without getMagnet but it is useless without it.